# ajustar el valor de un input de tipo select con e valor obtenido de la base de datos

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

tengo un campo de tipo select que obtiene sus valores de la base de datos, este es el codigo

```
<div class="col-3">
                    <h6 >Estado de la Averia</h6>
                    <select name="estadoAveria" id="estadoAveria" class="form-control custom-select required">
                        <option value="">Seleccione</option>
                        @foreach($estatuAveria as $estatu)
                            
                                <option value="{{$estatu->id_estatu}}"> {{ $estatu->descrip_estatu }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
</div>
```

necesito que al momento de editar este select obtenga el valor de la base de datos y por defecto dicho select se coloque en el valor, por ejemplo si el codigo que obtengo de la base de datos es 2 el estado de la averia selecionado debe de ser "En Proceso"

Comment: ¿Intentaste/investigaste algo al respecto?

Comment: si, consegui esta forma <?php $id_estatu == $estatu->id_estatu ?  'selected' : '' ?>, pero no me funciona

Comment: si, creo que si, realizare las pruebas, muchas gracias @porloscerrosΨ

Comment: Vale. Si te encuentras con algún problema actualiza la pregunta con lo que hayas probado y el resultado obtenido